# Split a dataset into two dataframes using multiple columns in R

Tags: r, split, dataframe, dplyr

Let's pretend my dataset looks like this:

```
working_data <- dplyr::data_frame("Date" = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-04"),
                                  "Time" = c("15:01", "15:01", "21:04", "13:19", "07:15", "07:15", "07:15"),
                                  "SeizureTime" = c("0:10", "0:07", "0:11", "0:04", "0:08", "0:06", "0:07"),
                                  "ET" = c("0:35", "0:35", "0:04", "1:10", "3:35", "3:35", "3:35"),
                                  "ONumber" = c("(123)555-1234", "(123)555-1234", "(123)555-9999", "(000)555-9876", "(123)555-1111", "(123)555-1111", "(123)555-1111"),
                                  "TNumber" = c("(123)555-1234", "(123)555-1234", "(123)555-9999", "(000)555-9876", "(123)555-1111", "(123)555-1111", "(123)555-1111"),
                                  "CT" = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b"))
```

I want to extract the rows from these data that are likely duplicates. My approach to doing this is the following:

```
while (nrow(working_data) != 0) {
          target_call <- working_data[1, ]
          working_data <- working_data[-1, ]
          similar_calls <- working_data %>% dplyr::filter(Date == target_call$Date,
                                                   Time == target_call$Time,
                                                   ET == target_call$ET,
                                                   ONumber == target_call$ONumber,
                                                   TNumber == target_call$TNumber)
```

The first loop through will set `target_call` equal to the first row of `working_data` and will set `similar_calls` equal to the second row. Assuming everything goes right... The problem I'm having is that once I run my functions on `target_call` and `similar_calls`, I don't want to see them again. So I want to remove the data from `working_data` that was pulled into `similar_calls`.

Once I have populated `target_call` and `similar_calls`, I need to decide which of the calls, if any, are the same as the `target_call` and then further decide which is the right one to choose and once I've chosen the right call, add it to a new dataset called `resolved_calls`. If there are calls left over in `similar_calls`, then I need to repeat the analysis of choosing a call and add one of those calls to `resolved_calls`.

The best way I can think of to do this would be to just split the data into two separate dataframes. But I don't know how to do that when I'm working with multiple columns. Is my only option a really ugly ifelse statement like:

```
working_data$Group <- ifelse(working_data$Date == target_call$Date & ... & working_data$TNumber == target_call$TNumber, 1, 0)
similar_calls <- working_data %>% dplyr::filter(Group == 1)
working_data <- working_data %>% dplyr::filter(Group == 0)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really described what you want to do with each group, but let's pretend that you just wanted to grab the first element in each group of similar calls. Then something like the `duplicated` function could work well:

```
working_data[with(working_data, !duplicated(paste(Date, Time, ET, ONumber, TNumber))),]
# Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
# 
#         Date  Time SeizureTime    ET       ONumber       TNumber    CT
#        (chr) (chr)       (chr) (chr)         (chr)         (chr) (chr)
# 1 2015-01-01 15:01        0:10  0:35 (123)555-1234 (123)555-1234     a
# 2 2015-01-02 21:04        0:11  0:04 (123)555-9999 (123)555-9999     b
# 3 2015-01-03 13:19        0:04  1:10 (000)555-9876 (000)555-9876     a
# 4 2015-01-04 07:15        0:08  3:35 (123)555-1111 (123)555-1111     b
```

In dplyr syntax you could use `group_by` to group by the appropriate elements, and then you could use `filter` with `row_number` to grab the first instance in each group:

```
working_data %>%
  group_by(Date, Time, ET, ONumber, TNumber) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
# Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
# Groups: Date, Time, ET, ONumber, TNumber [4]
# 
#         Date  Time SeizureTime    ET       ONumber       TNumber    CT
#        (chr) (chr)       (chr) (chr)         (chr)         (chr) (chr)
# 1 2015-01-01 15:01        0:10  0:35 (123)555-1234 (123)555-1234     a
# 2 2015-01-02 21:04        0:11  0:04 (123)555-9999 (123)555-9999     b
# 3 2015-01-03 13:19        0:04  1:10 (000)555-9876 (000)555-9876     a
# 4 2015-01-04 07:15        0:08  3:35 (123)555-1111 (123)555-1111     b
```

If you wanted to more generally process the groups, you could use `group_by` and then `summarize` to summarize the groups in different ways:

```
# Take text data in format mm:ss and return the number of seconds
secs <- function(x) {
  spl <- strsplit(x, ":")
  60*as.numeric(sapply(spl, "[", 1)) + as.numeric(sapply(spl, "[", 2))
}
working_data %>%
  group_by(Date, Time, ET, ONumber, TNumber) %>% 
  summarize(meanSeizure=mean(secs(SeizureTime)))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
# Groups: Date, Time, ET, ONumber [?]
# 
#         Date  Time    ET       ONumber       TNumber meanSeizure
#        (chr) (chr) (chr)         (chr)         (chr)       (dbl)
# 1 2015-01-01 15:01  0:35 (123)555-1234 (123)555-1234         8.5
# 2 2015-01-02 21:04  0:04 (123)555-9999 (123)555-9999        11.0
# 3 2015-01-03 13:19  1:10 (000)555-9876 (000)555-9876         4.0
# 4 2015-01-04 07:15  3:35 (123)555-1111 (123)555-1111         7.0
```

Comment: That is an extremely well thought out response, which I appreciate. I didn't realize until your answer that indicating what needs to be done with the data is important to how I go about splitting it. I'll revise the question to reflect that.